# How to split a string containing non-numeric characters into a string array in Go?

Tags: go

How would I split and filter a string containing non-numeric characters into a string array containing only numeric characters?

E.g.,

```
str := "035a 444$ bb" 
//split str into s
s := []string{"0", "3", "5", "4", "4", "4"}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to do two separate things here, so you need to first separate them in your mind:

First, you are trying to remove all non-numeric characters.

Second, you are trying to split all remaining characters into a slice containing single characters.

There is no built in function to remove non-numeric characters from a string, but you can write a regular expression match and replace to do this:

```
str := "035a 444$ bb"

reg, err := regexp.Compile("[^0-9]+")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

numericStr := reg.ReplaceAllString(str, "")
```

The regex matches any character that *is not* in 0-9 inclusive. Then [`regexp.ReaplceAllString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.ReplaceAllString) replaces those characters with nothing.

This causes `numericStr` to contain the string

```
"035444"
```

After that, you can use [`strings.Split()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) to get the slice you want.

```
s := strings.Split(numericStr, "")
```

The documentation tells us that:

> If sep is empty, Split splits after each UTF-8 sequence.

So `s` becomes:

```
[]string{"0", "3", "5", "4", "4", "4"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
func getNumericChars(s string) []string {
    var result []string
    // iterating through each character in string
    for _, c := range strings.Split(s, "") {
        // if character can be converted to number append it to result 
        if _, e := strconv.Atoi(c); e == nil {
            result = append(result, c)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

call `s := getNumericChars("035a 444$ bb")`.
 s will be `[0 3 5 4 4 4]`